# macOS Xcode, how to link/compile libvips as a static lib

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I have a small app called [Messer](https://messerapp.cc). It's a native macOS app using Swift and SwiftUI. The way the app works is by using the native macOS apis to manipulate the image (NSImage) and finally saves a png file to disk. Further conversion to other formats (with optimization) is left to embedded binaries of popular open source libraries.

The problem is that the conversion and manipulation is too slow, for smallish images it's fine, but anything over a mb makes the app choke. I'm looking for ways to (radically) improve the performance and I came across [libvips](https://github.com/libvips/libvips), it even has support for webp. So basically I would like to migrate all the image manipulation code to libvips. However, I'm a complete noob when comes to compilation toolchains and what not.

Could anyone give me a hand and provide some detailed instructions on how would I go about embedding the library in my macOS Xcode project and further then get it to compile statically (due to all the dependencies it has).

I would greatly appreciate it!

Edit: I just realized libvips is GPL which means I cannot embed it without releasing the source code of my app. Which is something I do not want to do. I will leave the question open for future reference though, maybe someone needs it at some point.

Comment: libvips is LGPL (not GPL) so it's fine to use in closed-source and commercial apps. It can be configured to use some GPL loaders (eg. poppler, for PDF loading), so don't enable those features if you want to keep your source closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully static library is difficult, and probably not necessary.

libvips itself is easy to build static, but it has a lot of dependencies (it can be more than 40 other projects), and you'll need to make static versions of all those libraries too. It's a lot of very annoying work.

Instead, I would use homebrew to build a vips area, and take a copy of that.

Wipe your homebrew install area, do a fresh install, then `brew install vips`. Take a copy of the brew area, trim out stuff you don't need (there's a fair amount you can cut away, you probably only need `lib` and `include`, make a script to do this for you), and copy that tree into your project.

You might need to set some environment variables like `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to get it to link.

You'll need to be careful that you don't include any licensed code. Poppler, for example, which libvips can use for PDF load, is GPL and you mustn't use that. It might be worth making your own libvips binary that only enables the dependencies you want.

I have a repo here:

https://github.com/jcupitt/build-osx

That builds a macOS .app for this thing:

https://github.com/libvips/nip2

It uses jhbuild to make the whole libvips stack from scratch and then package it. I don't think jhbuild is a a good solution for you directly, but you could probably adapt some of the packaging scripts.

Comment: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` has nothing to do with link, it's for runtime. libvips provides a pkg-config file for compilation & link.

Comment: Yes, you need to set it to get it to link correctly at runtime. macOS apps are relocatable, so you can't rely on rpath and friends.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply jcupitt, I've given up on the effort, but the info will surely be useful for other people in the future!

Comment: I added a link to a project of mine that builds a libvips-based macOS application. I don't think it'd be directly useful, but you might be able to adapt the packaging scripts.